# Angular UI-Bootstrap Injector Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to use angular ui-bootstrap on my project. After adding the required script dependencies in my layout.cshtml, I get the following error;

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/unpr?p0=%24modalProvider%20%3C-%20%24modal%20%3C-%20app.views.teachersWorkSchdules.index
    at http://localhost:6634/Scripts/angular.min.js:6:416
    at http://localhost:6634/Scripts/angular.min.js:41:121
    at Object.d [as get] (http://localhost:6634/Scripts/angular.min.js:39:92)
    at http://localhost:6634/Scripts/angular.min.js:41:195
    at d (http://localhost:6634/Scripts/angular.min.js:39:92)
    at Object.e [as invoke] (http://localhost:6634/Scripts/angular.min.js:39:362)
    at M.instance (http://localhost:6634/Scripts/angular.min.js:80:336)
    at D (http://localhost:6634/Scripts/angular.min.js:61:362)
    at g (http://localhost:6634/Scripts/angular.min.js:55:105)
    at http://localhost:6634/Scripts/angular.min.js:54:249 <div ui-view="" class="shuffle-animation col-xs-12 ng-scope" data-ng-animate="1">
```

This is a part of the head section of the layout.cshtml;

```
<!-- SignalR scripts -->
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
    @Html.IncludeScript("~/Abp/Framework/scripts/libs/abp.signalr.js")

    @Scripts.Render("~/Bundles/App/Main/js")

    <!-- UIGrid References -->
    @*<script src="~/Scripts/ui-grid.min.js"></script>*@
    @*<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>*@
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.4.0.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the controller in which I wanna use the ui-bootstrap;

```
(function () {
    angular.module('app').controller('app.views.workSchdules.createDialog', [
        '$scope', '$log', '$modalInstance', 'abp.services.app.workDay', 
        function ($scope, $log, $modalInstance, workDayService) {
            var vm = this;

            $scope.mytime = new Date();
            $scope.ismeridian = true;

            $scope.changed = function () {
                $log.log('Time changed to: ' + $scope.mytime);
            };

            vm.workDays = [];

            function getWorkDays() {
                workDayService.getAllWorkDaysList().success(function (data) {
                    vm.workDays = data.items;
                });
            }


        }
    ]);


})();
```

Please I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I've been on this for several hours. Please help.

Comment: Have you added `'ui.bootstrap'` into the app module?

Comment: @AlonEitan where exactly do I add it to?

Comment: In the part of your code where you created the module: `angular.module("app", ['ui.bootstrap', ......]);`

Comment: @AlonEitan I did as you asked and got this new error;      `Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/ng/areq?p0=app.views.layout&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at angular.js:38
    at qb (angular.js:1815)
    at Qa (angular.js:1825)
    at angular.js:9158
    at w (angular.js:8228)
    at D (angular.js:8270)
    at g (angular.js:7731)
    at g (angular.js:7734)
    at angular.js:7611
    at angular.js:1681`

Comment: I'll give you a nice tip to debug it: Don't use the minified angular, instead of including `~/Scripts/angular.min.js`, change it to `~/Scripts/angular.js` - Then you'll see more detailed description of the error. When you figured it out you can change back to the minified file

Comment: @AlonEitan "Tried to load Angular more than once" was the description it gave. I'm so lost. I thought this would just be a simple plug an play thing.

Comment: What's `"~/Scripts/ui-grid.min.js"`? Is it angular ui-grid? if so - load it AFTER the `angular.js` file

Comment: @AlonEitan It's commented. I'm not using it.

Comment: Please read http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ - There are some dependencies missing (Angular-touch). But unfortunately I'm out of ideas - You should include more code - Please show how you created the module (`angular.module("app", [ ...... ]);`)